# Entity Relationship Diagram - Entity depending on attribute

Tags: relational-theory, database-diagrams, entity-framework, relations

I have an ER-Diagram containing the entity employees. When employees have high skills they may supervise lower skilled employees. How can I model that in an ER-Diagram?

My initial approach of was to have a disjunction of high skilled and low-skilled employees. But that appears to be rather inconvenient.

[image]

Comment: *When employees have high skills they may supervise lower skilled employees.* It is a process (calculated/dynamic relation), not a relation or attribute. It has no static mirror in a diagram.

Comment: @Akina so the way I did it (added picture to question) does not work?

Comment: It MAY work... but you'll need to use special techniques (triggers) to provide real-time data consistency - each skill may alter causing to recalculate admin rights and add/remove records into relational table. Whereas the actual data you want to store may be easily obtained by one simple query.

Comment: I find the diagram just fine, expressing the scenario you describe correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
( empno ... not null primary key
, skilllevel ... not null
);

CREATE TABLE Supervising
( supervisor_empno ... not null references Employees (empno)
, empno ... not null references Employees (empno)
, primary key (supervisor_empno, empno)
);
```

If you want to guarantee the skilllevel in supervising:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
( empno ... not null primary key
, skilllevel ... not null
, unique (skilllevel, empno)
, check (skillevel in ('High', 'Low'))
);

CREATE TABLE Supervising
( supervisor_empno ... not null 
, supervisor_skillevel ... not null
,    foreign key (supervisor_skillevel, supervisor_empno)
     references Employees (skillevel, empno)    
, empno ... not null references Employees (empno)
, empno_skillevel ... not null
,    foreign key (skillevel, empno)
     references Employees (skillevel, empno)    
, check (supervisor_skillevel = 'High')
, check (skillevel = 'Low')
, primary key (supervisor_empno, empno)
);
```